# Not producing the textfield output

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flashdevelop

This code produces no errors but the TextField gives no output.
I tried this with a simpler code and the valuelocal has a value and gives an output however I need a smaller font size and anyway I need another Textfield with much bigger font so I determined that I needed to preload the font

I was referring.
 http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/AS3-flash-runtime-font-loading-embedding

So what is going wrong here?

Correction- I thought output was results- I get a dozen panels loading other than output. Cut out a few lines. The numbers are trace from Main.as

```
Building New Project
mxmlc -load-config+=obj\NewProjectConfig.xml -debug=true -incremental=true -o obj\NewProject635574676017466150
Starting java as: java.exe -Xmx384m -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -
INITIALIZING: Adobe Flex Compiler SHell (fcsh)
Starting new compile.
Loading configuration file ...\frameworks\flex-config.xml
Loading configuration file ...\NewProjectConfig.xml
obj\NewProject635574676017466150 (5264 bytes)
(fcsh)Build succeeded
Done(0)
[Starting debug session with FDB]
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
Successfully loaded FontArial (../bin/js/Arial.swf)
Successfully loaded FontArial (../bin/js/Arial.swf)
Successfully loaded FontArial (../bin/js/Arial.swf)
Successfully loaded FontArial (../bin/js/Arial.swf)
Successfully loaded FontArial (../bin/js/Arial.swf)
Successfully loaded FontArial (../bin/js/Arial.swf)
Successfully loaded FontArial (../bin/js/Arial.swf
```

This is my code :

```
package {

        import flash.display.Bitmap;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.text.TextField;
        import flash.text.TextFormat;
        import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
        import flash.text.AntiAliasType;
        import flash.display.Loader;
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import flash.text.Font;
        import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

        /**
         * ...
         * @author Michael
         */

        public class tile extends Sprite {

            public static const FONT_NAME:String = "Arial";
            public static const FONT_EXPORT_NAME:String = "FontArial";
            public static const FONT_FILE_NAME:String = "../bin/js/Arial.swf";

            private function onFontLoaded(e:Event):void {
                trace("Successfully loaded " + FONT_EXPORT_NAME + " (" + FONT_FILE_NAME + ")");
                if (e.target.applicationDomain.hasDefinition(FONT_EXPORT_NAME))
                {
                    var FontClass:Class = e.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition(FONT_EXPORT_NAME) as Class;
                    Font.registerFont(FontClass);
                    init();
                }
                else
                {
                    trace("Missing " + FONT_EXPORT_NAME + "!");
                }
            }

            private function onFontLoadingFailed(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
                trace("Missing " + FONT_FILE_NAME);
            }

            [Embed(source = "C:/my_absolute_local_path/Games/New            Project/bin/js/blank.png")]
            private var blank:Class;
            private var b1:Bitmap;
            private var valuelocal:int;
            public function tile(value:int):void {
                valuelocal = value;
                var loader:Loader = new Loader();
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFontLoaded);
                loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onFontLoadingFailed);
                loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR, onFontLoadingFailed);
                loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.VERIFY_ERROR, onFontLoadingFailed);
                loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.DISK_ERROR, onFontLoadingFailed);
                loader.load(new URLRequest(FONT_FILE_NAME));
            }
            private function init():void {

                b1 = new blank  ;
                this.addChild(b1);

                /*    var myText:TextField = new TextField();*/
                /*myText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
                    myText.text = valuelocal.toString(); 
                    myText.x = 17;
                    myText.y = 17;*/

                var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                format.font = FONT_NAME;
                format.size = 20;
                format.color = 0x000000;

                var field:TextField = new TextField();
                field.defaultTextFormat = format;
                field.text = valuelocal.toString();
                field.x = field.y = 10;
                field.embedFonts = true;
                field.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
                this.addChild(field);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not getting any traces at all?  Try putting a trace after `loader.load`.    Is it a application size thing that makes you not want to embed it in the main application?

Comment: Try these listeners instead:  `loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onFontLoaded);` `loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onFontLoadingFailed);`

Comment: And you could try adding a context to your loader.    `var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();`   `context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;`   `loader.load(new URLRequest(FONT_FILE_NAME), context);`

Comment: No traces at all- I have a trace in the Main.as with no results in any popup windows- variables etc and it loads all of them . I put it there if I could access it in this- tile.as but I have failed to access public var using methods listed in StackExchange. This is after uninstall and reinstall of FD- its 4.7.

Comment: But are you 100% sure those traces are being reached? If so, then you must some kind of environment issue like lacking the proper flash debug player.  Download that here: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: Just put in flashplayer_16_sa_debug.exe - It made no difference.

Comment: Try the activeX one, I think that may be what flashdevelop uses. Or better yet,  in FlashDevelop go to **tools -> install software** and get them that way.